# How to ignore win32 exception? module process

Tags: c#

i tried to create to look dll that loaded in process. but i got error when getting process with system.dll. it throw error message:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Unable to enumerate the process modules.'

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace dll
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in processlist)
            {


                foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules)
                {
                    if (module.FileName.Contains("foo.dll"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(module.FileName);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what is this? how to fix this?

Comment: That's probably because you don't have enough privileges to access all processes in the system.

Comment: put in some try/catch statements so you can say "I couldnt read that" and then move on

Comment: @Nichie I tried to run my app in admnistrator privelege i get error too.

Comment: @BugFinder example code ?  i try this `try { my code} catch (InvalidCastException e)   
{  
}` get same error.

Answer (score 0):

This will ignore Exceptions thrown by accessing process.Modules.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetProcessFileName(string searchBy)
{
    foreach(var process in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        try{
            var p = process.Modules.Cast<ProcessModule>()
                .Where(m => m.FileName.Contains(searchBy))
                .Select(x => x.FileName);           
            return p;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //write to log
            //Console.Write(e);     
        }
    }

    return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}
```

Comment: can u simplify fix my code not write new code? i'm not so expert to understand your code without explanation. thx by the way

Comment: I moved the query to a method. I used LINQ instead of a second foreach loop. Used Cast<ProcessModule> as ProcessModuleCollection does not implement IQueryable (required for Where). Surrounded LINQ with try catch block, as process.Module will throw exceptions. Return directly if an item is found otherwise return an empty Enumerable.